# OverwriteModelError in Mongoose — can't find the problem in the code

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am designing a todo-list application in MERN-stack. In Express I have got some entry points, which are being invoked in React. There is an error however, whose nature I cannot understand. Here's my entire code:

```
const express = require('express')
const config = require('config')
const app = express()
const port = config.get("PORT")
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const mng = require('./db/mongoose')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.post('/todo-submit', async (req, res) => {

  let message = {}

  const item = {
    task: req.body.task,
    dueDate: req.body.dueDate,
    isAccomplished: false
  };

  const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    task: String,
    dueDate: Date,
    isAccomplished: Boolean
  }, {versionKey: false});

  const todoModel = mongoose.model("todo", todoSchema, "todo")
  try {
    await todoModel.create(item)

    message = {'success': true, 'message': 'Records have been successfully inserted'}
  }

  catch (error) {
    message = {'success': false, 'errorMessage': error}
  }

  res.json(message)

})

app.get('/fetch_records', async (req,res) => {
  
  const fetchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    task: String,
    dueDate: Date
  });

  
  const fetchModel = mongoose.model("todo", fetchSchema);
  try {
    
    const records = await fetchModel.find({})
    res.json(records);
  }

  catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).json({message: 'There was an error while fetching records'})
  }

  finally {
    mongoose.connection.close()
  }

});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("This server has been started on port " + port + "!")
})
```

The entry point `fetch_records` does not work at all.

The error occurs namely here:

```
const fetchModel = mongoose.model("todo", fetchSchema);
```

I'm starting the server and trying to load the page on the frontend. As soon as the page is loaded, the express server crashes with the message stated in the topic of this post.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new mongoose schema (fetchSchema) and trying to create a model with name `todo` using that schema. However, you have already defined the `todo` model with a different schema in the `/todo-submit` route.
You should give it a different name, for example `fetchTodo`.

you should also write schema and models outside of your routes, otherwise they will be created every time you follow a route:

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require('config');
const app = express();
const port = config.get("PORT");
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const mng = require('./db/mongoose');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Define the "todo" model
const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  task: String,
  dueDate: Date,
  isAccomplished: Boolean
}, { versionKey: false });

const todoModel = mongoose.model("todo", todoSchema, "todo");

// Define the "fetchTodo" model
const fetchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  task: String,
  dueDate: Date
});

const fetchTodoModel = mongoose.model("fetchTodo", fetchSchema, "todo");

app.post('/todo-submit', async (req, res) => {
  let message = {};

  const item = {
    task: req.body.task,
    dueDate: req.body.dueDate,
    isAccomplished: false
  };

  try {
    await todoModel.create(item);
    message = { 'success': true, 'message': 'Records have been successfully inserted' };
  } catch (error) {
    message = { 'success': false, 'errorMessage': error };
  }

  res.json(message);
});

app.get('/fetch_records', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const records = await fetchTodoModel.find({});
    res.json(records);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'There was an error while fetching records' });
  } finally {
    mongoose.connection.close();
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("This server has been started on port " + port + "!");
});
```